# Plotting columns from a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, simulation

I've created a matrix of values from a simulation that is stored in 20x7 matrix (20 observations across 7 columns of numbers; the matrix is called output).  The columns are output from a simulation.

After running the simulation, I included column names:

```
colnames(output) <- c('level', 'value1','value2','value3',
                         'value4','value5','value6')
```

And the matrix looks nice and clean. when observing:

```
output
```

Is there a way to plot these columns from the matrix?  I've tried the code below (and other variants), but it will not work.

```
 plot(level$output, value1$output)
```

thanks!

Comment: to plot multiple columns, try `matplot(output$level, output[,-1], t="l", lty=1)`. Or, `library(ggplot2) ; qplot(level, value, colour=variable, geom="line", data=melt(output, id="level"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To index the matrix you use `output[,'level']`, i.e. "any row, the 'level' column".

```
plot(output[,'level'],output[,'value1'])
```

For your interest, you could also make a data frame from your matrix and plot like so:

```
df <- data.frame(output)
plot(value1 ~ level,df)
```

Not worth doing if all you are doing with `output` is plotting, but if you are doing other sorts of analysis on `output` in R, a dataframe can be handy (and then you can refer to columns like `output$level`, `output$value1` whereas with a matrix you have to do `output[,'level']`).