# Plotting Matrix with R like data.frame

Tags: r, matrix

*This question is more advanced than the similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919712/plotting-columns-from-a-matrix-in-r). Expected amount of chars about 20.*

When I plot things in data.frame, I do it like:

```
# t1 is a df
> plot((q1*s1+q2*s2)/(s1+s2),data=t1)
```

but can I reuse this form for matrix?

**[Finally working MVO, thanks!]**

```
> M<-matrix(data=rnorm(30),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c('q1','q2')))
> plot(M)
> x=1:dim(M)[1]
> plot(x~q1/q2,data=data.frame(M),type='l')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **with** for this

```
with(data.frame(mymatrix), plot((q1*s1+q2*q2)/(s1+s2)))
```

Hope this help

Comment: +1 this worked but why not the other method, still thinking. Added MVO to trial -- should I initiate vars differently?

Comment: Again, the formula method only works when you provide a *valid formula* -- you need to plot something versus something else (notice the `~` symbol in the example I gave). Providing just one value is not a valid formula because R doesn't know if it's y or x or what to plot it against.

Answer (score 1):

That sort of plotting (where you type formulas involving the dataframe's columns) is only available for data frames.

If `colnames(mymatrix)` are `q1`, `s1`, etc, then you can achieve the affect by doing:

```
plot( myformula, data=data.frame(mymatrix))
```

i.e., coerce the matrix to a dataframe and then use the formula.

## Update

An example demonstrating this works:

```
# construct a matrix
> mymatrix <- array(runif(10*2),dim=c(10,2))
# give it column names X and Y
> colnames(mymatrix)<-c('X','Y')
> mymatrix
               X          Y
 [1,] 0.07346608 0.81321578
 [2,] 0.09525474 0.17852467
 [3,] 0.81246522 0.45747972
 [4,] 0.01286714 0.82517127
 [5,] 0.77554012 0.87725725
 [6,] 0.71908435 0.71628493
 [7,] 0.13212848 0.67827601
 [8,] 0.65993809 0.01650703
 [9,] 0.11385161 0.99433644
[10,] 0.22750439 0.45611635
# plot Y vs X -- note you need to convert the matrix to a data frame first.
> plot(Y~X,data.frame(mymatrix))
```

Comment: Ahh, it doesn't work because the example you gave doesn't work (the one where t1 is a data frame up top).

Comment: I've given an example showing my solution works. The reason yours doesn't is because the very first line of code you gave as an example ('when I plot things like a data.frame, I do it like') won't work - it's not a valid formula. I only used your example in my answer because you said it worked in your question, and I assumed it did as I had no sample data to recreate your problem.

Comment: If you use the formula method it works but try plot(Y/X, data.frame(mymatrix))...doesn't work because there is no "data" parameters in the default method !!!! So i agree with mathematical.coffee the first example were not valid even with a data.frame

Comment: @hhh - now that you have cleared up what the problem is (it's that your original code was invalid, let alone anything to do with matrices) - what are you intending to plot those numbers *against*, ie what is the x value? If you just want to plot them against `1:n` (n being the number of rows of the matrix), then the solution is to use @dickoa's method -- use `with(data.frame(mymatrix),plot(...))` and omit the `data=...` argument from `plot`. hope that helps

Comment: As I said hhh - the reason your formula is not valid is because you are not plotting *against* anything - in that case @dickoa's answer will work for you.

Comment: @hhh: I don't think i'm wrong anyway my solution works but "plot((q1*s1+q2*s2)/(s1+s2),data=t1)" wont work even if "t1" is a valid data.frame. Because you don't use the formula interface. Build a dataframe a try

Comment: +1 for the tilde and falsifying my MVOs, now they should work. Thank you.